# Search incorrectly returns no results

Tags: bug, search

If I search for `python process_time` (no quotes) I get no results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+process_time. But there are clearly pages that contain both keywords, for example [Class method performance test during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126570/class-method-performance-test-during-execution/24126681#24126681) and [Measure time elapsed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python/21455138#21455138). Is this a bug in the search engine?

UPDATE:

Let me see if I understood this right.

As @MartinSmith said, a search unit is a post not a page (and from results it seems comments aren't included, only questions and answers).

As @Braiam said, search skips anything inside "code blocks". So even if though one of the answers actually contained both words, it didn't count because `process_time` was inside backquotes.

What is still strange is that when I search for just one keyword (process_time), the answer where it's inside the code block still shows up.

Comment: Search searches posts not pages.

Answer (score 2):

Search ignores code blocks, so https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+code%3Aprocess_time is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Seems to work but I don't see `code:` as a valid option here? http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @MartinSmith there have been cases where the search documentation is stale (like using relative dates), fill a bug report.

Comment: How did you know it existed though? Must be documented somewhere?

Comment: @MartinSmith if I have to answer your question truthfully, I would say it was osmosis, really

Comment: But how come http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=process_time gives the first result where process_time is inside a code block?

Comment: @MartinSmith The best "documentation" I can find for `code:` is [Search for just code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122792) and [this feature request for it to be documented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166835) (which is marked as complete even though it is not in the help center page), also [this question asking why it isn't documented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146827), which is answered in the comments with a link to [another comment on the first question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122792/search-for-operators#comment326666_122792).

Comment: @TinyGiant hopefully the feature is not still in testing.

Comment: @MartinSmith 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @max in both of the first two results, `process_time` occurred *outside* of code blocks, and [`[python] process_time`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+process_time) returns questions or answers to questions tagged python where `process_time` occurs in the body, outside of code.

Comment: @TinyGiant are you ordering by relevance? This is the first result for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/24126681/73226. The only references are in back ticks or doesn't that count as a code block?

Comment: Hmm, didn't notice that one. It might be that it is not in a code *block*, but it is inline formatted code, treated like text. @MartinSmith

Comment: @TinyGiant regardless of how search defines what to include and what to exclude by default, the behavior is still inconsistent: the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24126681/73226 shows up when searching for `process_time` but not when searching for `python process_time` - even though `python` is clearly plain text in there.

Comment: Code blocks are evidently **not** excluded, but searching for *phrases* in codeblocks appears to be broken. Compare [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Index+is+not+backed+up+by+an+existing+repository+created%3A2015-01-31) with the [exact phrase search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Index+is+not+backed+up+by+an+existing+repository%22+created%3A2015-01-31); the words `backed` and `repository` only appear in a codeblock. You can update the search to only include those two words and the [post in question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28246887) still appears.