# How to search for an answer containing two specific words?

Tags: support, search

I was trying to search for an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653385/perl-replace-ambiguous-letters-with-each-option/37663394#37663394) I gave some months ago. I recalled that it had the words `bless` and `recursion`, so I tried enter the following in the search box: [`user:2173773 is:answer bless recursion`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2173773+is%3Aanswer+bless+recursion). Unfortunately, this gave [zero results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2173773+is%3Aanswer+bless+recursion). However, if I searched for [`user:2173773 is:answer bless`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2173773+is%3Aanswer+bless) it found the post, and also if I searched for [`user:2173773 is:answer recursion`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2173773+is%3Aanswer+recursion) it found it.

So, yes I found the post I was looking for, but the question is if it is possible to combine terms (like in this case `bless` and `recursion`) to narrow down the list of results?

Comment: Searching on meta for [`user:2173773 is:question Bless recursion`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2173773+is%3Aquestion+bless+recursion) finds this question fine!

Comment: [user:2173773 is:answer code:"bless" recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2173773+is%3Aanswer+code%3A%22bless%22+recursion) works, but don't ask me where I saw the `code:` syntax, it isn't in the help center... Maybe someone with more knowledge on that can answer...

Comment: Ha, I found a comment about that `code:` "feature" which allows to search inside code blocks: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313535/search-incorrectly-returns-no-results#comment287753_313537

Comment: @Tunaki: well remembered! Not only did I not know this, but also I never realized *code is not searched*. [tag:status-by-design]?

Comment: @RadLexus but it is searched as the answer shows up when searching for "bless" on its own without any `code:` qualifier. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2173773+is%3Aanswer+bless

Comment: @MartinSmith: then I see no rational explanation at all...

Comment: So `user:2173773 is:answer bless recursion` fails, `user:2173773 is:answer bless` works, `user:2173773 is:answer recursion` works, `recursion user:2173773 is:answer bless` fails, `user:2173773 is:answer using recursion` finds a *different* answer of yours but not that one (so it's not searching for a phrase)... The answer is *weeks* old and should be correctly indexed at this point. This is a straight-up bug in a critical feature of the site.

Comment: Upvoted, but this is a symptom of a much bigger problem. It's hard to find anything on SO. I find myself constantly exiting SO, going to Google, and using it to search only SO pages. That's an indication that the system needs serious improvement. Our internal search should be BETTER than a web crawler's, not worse.

Comment: @nhouser9 I don't think that is very realistic. Search is a core product for Google and they spend a *lot* of resources on it. How would any internal search be able to compete with that? That said, the internal search should certainly be improved.

Comment: Recommend adding [tag:bug] to this, as it clearly is one.