# Blacklist [dollar-sign]

Tags: discussion, tags, blocklist-request

I encountered a question just now whose sole and only tag was [dollar-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dollar-sign). I repaired it to have a tag that actually might cause it to be found by someone who could answer it. Then I did a quick tag search.

I don't know how this tag came into being, but it seems to me to be one of those attractive nuisances that leads new users astray. Could it possibly be blacklisted?

Comment: I don't see any value in it at all. Perhaps it should be removed entirely instead of just black listed?

Comment: Black listing seems a bit extreme, unless this is a recurring problem tag. Deleting it should be sufficient

Comment: Actually I am an expert on the dollar sign, its a very useful tag for me....

Comment: @AshleyMedway you should totally drop that and use jQuery

Comment: @Braiam I tried using jQuery in regular expressions but I found that `$` works much better

Comment: Probably exists because it is/was really hard to search for `$`.

Comment: Can one be an expert in `$`? How about an expert in `&` or `~`?

Answer (score 15):

There is no reason for this tag to exist. Having the phrase in the body/title should be enough.

If you need to search for a dollar sign (in code, obviously), you can use the search. Just go to the corner of any page and type in `code:"$"`.

I explained this feature here: [Why aren't we told we can use special characters in search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/6083675)

---

### I suggest we make this tag burn... Like a hole in your pocket.

(We don't need to blacklist it, since blacklisting must be done by community managers; even diamond moderators can't do it.)

Comment: Most code in Shell or Perl contains `$`, but isn't necessarily *about* `$` - so would be found by your search, but not relevant to what you were looking for.

Comment: How do you burn a hole?

Comment: Whether we need to blacklist it and whether we can blacklist it are entirely orthogonal.

Answer (score 11):

I would be willing to wager that the impetus for tags like this is due to the strange difficulty which exists to search for simple operators, such as but not limited to `$`, `~`, and `&`.  In fact, we have tags for [tilde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tilde) and [ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ampersand), which not only have very *few* questions in general, but also are attached to some very *good* questions.  Looking at [dollar-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dollar-sign), there are also some decent questions there which very clearly relate **to the use of `$`** in one form or another.

Getting rid of this tag would be a mistake.  Making questions about these operators easier to find on Google is only ever a good thing, and taking away the tag would hamper our ability to do that.

Comment: For search, there's symbol hound... we don't need a tag solely for the purpose of searching... tags are first and foremost meant to bring experts to questions they are able to answer. The searching part, was just a nice side effect.

Comment: Perhaps we only need [tag:double-quote] then?

Comment: Perhaps it should be renamed `operator-dollar-sign`, if it's useful for finding questions specifically about the operator.  It would help to prevent it from being used in general purpose questions tangentially related to dollar signs.

Comment: @JustinTime:  I'm actually really okay with that solution.

Comment: @JustinTime : What about the use of the tag [tag:dollar-sign] for questions that involve currency formatting? And before you answer that, consider that there's also a [tag:euro] tag, that is currently used in 73 questions.

Comment: Looks like [ampersand] is being used as a synonym of [ampersand.js] on occasion. Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558631/ampersand-fetch-children-collection-with-parent) which contains no `&` what so ever.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$` can't be used as a tag, I guess some people thought [dollar-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dollar-sign) was the next best thing. As [Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto) [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335976/1946501), there's also a an [ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ampersand) and [tilde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tilde) tag that correspond with respectively the `&` and `~` symbols.

At the moment of my typing this answer, there are 123 questions tagged [dollar-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dollar-sign), which IMO is quite significant. Those questions involve questions about programming environments as diverse as [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell), [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell), [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [nsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsis) & [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) (where the `$` is commonly used in code) as well as eg. currency formatting (for obvious reasons).

I've checked only a few of the aforementioned questions, but those that I did check were all legitimate questions that are totally on-topic on StackOverflow. So, considering the number of contexts where people may want to raise totally on-topic questions about the symbol `$`, I would agree with Makoto and don't support burninating the [dollar-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dollar-sign) tag.

---

#### Note

Renaming the tag [dollar-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dollar-sign) to [operator-dollar-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator-dollar-sign) won't cover all valid use cases of the [dollar-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dollar-sign) tag. For example, it wouldn't cover questions that involve currency formatting or conversion.

And with respect to currency formatting or conversion, I'd like to point out that there's currently - when typing this note - also a [euro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/euro) tag, which is used in 73 questions.