# What magic are you using to find duplicate questions in reasonable amount of time?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Often I google my question, find no answer on Stack Overflow then ask a question, look through "Questions that may already have your answer" and see nothing reasonable and then someone marks my question as duplicate.

What's the method they are using?

Comment: Google/your question is common and they are used to the topic so they know where to find it.

Comment: _"What's the method they are using?"_ Bookmark lists with the well known canonical questions. Some mind mapping also, and google of course.

Comment: You can use a site specific search from google as well (append site:stackoverflow.com to the search string) and that will return results only on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Due to their better understanding of the programming language and their experience, they often can come up with better search terms than you. Sometimes they have also seen the duplicate when it was posted. Getting a question closed as a duplicate is no reason for shame if you have done your research. It might help others finding the duplicate through your question.

Comment: All good answers. I guess someone could promote all of these comments into an answer

Comment: A lot of it is vocabulary too.  If you're that little bit more experienced with a topic, then you know the proper names for all of the concepts associated with it, which makes finding information about it really easy.

Comment: Black magic, white magic, sometimes grey magic.

Comment: You've never googled a lot till you see [this message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8LkRo.png). (Yes, I was backed off when I tried to search for 30 dupes simultaneously)

Answer (score 8):

I'm annoyed by this too—but I know *why it happens*.

The "questions that may have your answer" dropdown is *by no means* the only similar questions. It only goes by your question title, which might be vague (like [some that I've improved](//stackoverflow.com/posts/39821820/revisions)), and you really can't expect it to *search through every single question* looking for the one that might just have your answer.

Close voters, though. I think that [the original dupehammer answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/335772) gives a pretty good explanation:

> If you have a gold badge in your tag, you *know* what's been asked before, in several iterations, and where to find it.

Comment: *It only goes by your question title, which might be vague* - Indeed. And that's assuming the title even contains a question or matches the issue described in the post.

Answer (score 7):

Usually, when I mark a question as duplicate, it's because I've answered a similar question before.  Stack Overflow has some neat search filters you can use.  For example, I'll usually search my own answers (or questions) with a specific word I know was used in the question.

[image]

You can see the full list of advanced search options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: "You can see the full list of advanced search options here" Well, no. They don't list the very best search operator [`code:`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/6083675).