# How does a question become a hot network question?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Some questions become hot network questions. How exactly does this happen?

[image]

Comment: @CodyGray thanks, I definitely need a lesson on how to accurately find duplicates, perhaps I should ask a question about that... So you can find me a duplicate ;)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359336/how-can-i-find-duplicate-questions-before-i-post-a-new-one or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338097/what-magic-are-you-using-to-find-duplicate-questions-in-reasonable-amount-of-tim? ;-p

Comment: as far as i understand it, it relates to the number of viewers that look into the question, if it surpasses a threshold your question is hot