# Please enable "symbol" search

Tags: feature-request, search

I wanted to read about `??` in PHP.

I searched, `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3F%3F`.

It returns 0 results.

But there are good questions, like *[C#'s null coalescing operator (??) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278835/cs-null-coalescing-operator-in-php)*, about `??` in PHP.

So can you please enable "symbol" search also.

Comment: This used to be possible, but [it broke at some point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters#comment868700_161785)

Comment: @Stijn: Searching for `code:"??"` works for me, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nope, what the answer suggests only searches in code blocks. What OP is asking here is supposed to work as I mentioned already.

Comment: A feature request to change the current behavior doesn't seem like a dup of the "How to do X" when it is only a partial solution (like in this case)

Comment: This has been broken for as long as [main] has existed. The problem was reported as early as during the private beta, way back when such reports where still on the uservoice site. It was briefly fixed around 2014, but has been broken again since circa 2015, with no acknowledgement by the dev team until now that it even *is* broken, let alone that they are working on fixing it.

Comment: Google for "php double question mark site:stackoverflow.com" found the result you mentioned at about 4th one. And remembering the name of the 95 printable ASCII characters is not difficult.

Comment: Alternatively, [use SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3F%3F+php&l=&e=&n=&u=stackoverflow.com). // But because people like "spamming" their question with `?`s it doesn't really work well in this case. I hate those SO bad users. The [first search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094889/how-to-use-rapidshare-api-to-get-account-details-php-question) is not even an acceptable SO question nowadays.

Comment: How would such a symbol search work with *I need help?????*?? :-) Smiley aside, there are probably at least a few thousand questions on SO that contain *??* somewhere within them. How would a symbol search work with those? Or questions for C/C++/Java/Python/CountlessOthers for symbols like *++*? (Oops! I used *++* when I wrote *C/C++/Java* - another useless symbol search result. Drat! Two more! Oh, wait... what about not *!* in C/C++/Java/Python/JS/??)

Comment: SymbolHound, referenced in *[We need to be able to search for punctuation (symbols)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/)*, has been dead [since April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).

Answer (score 11):

Normal searches ignore special characters. To search for special characters, use the `code` operator, like so:

[`php code:"??"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+code%3A%22%3F%3F%22)

While searching like this does occasionally run into issues (e.g. can't search for `"`), in this case it seems to work well enough. The question you are looking for is the fourth result.

See also my question: [Why aren't we told we can use special characters in search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/6083675)

Answer (score 8):

As this is unlikely to get implemented I have created a query in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to aid in these kind of searches.

Be warned that SQL Server without full-text indexes is having a hard time to find post with just a simple `LIKE` statement. That is why the query must be run on small sets, here achieved by insisting on selecting a tag. If the query times out, reduce the number of posts you want to include. Fork the query in that case and make your own adjustments.

Here is [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1591052/symbol-search?symbol=%5B%3C-&tag=r). It does try to escape the [, _ and % characters as those have special meaning in a `LIKE` operator within SQL Server. If something seems wonky try without any of those characters.

```sql
declare @symbolsearch nvarchar(200) = ##symbol:string##
declare @tag nvarchar(35) = ##tag:string?r##

set @symbolsearch = replace(@symbolsearch,'[', '[[]');
set @symbolsearch = replace(@symbolsearch,'_', '[_]');
set @symbolsearch = replace(@symbolsearch,'%', '[%]');

print @symbolsearch

;with tagposts as (
select p.id 
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where tagname = @tag
),
posthistoryedits as (
  select ph.postid
       , max(ph.id) [latestid]
  from posthistory ph 
  inner join tagposts tp on tp.id = ph.postid
  where posthistorytypeid in (2,5)
  group by ph.postid
),
posthistorytext as (
  select ph.postid
       , ph.text
  from posthistory ph
  inner join posthistoryedits phe on phe.latestid = ph.id
)

select  top 50
       -- count(*)
       p.id as [Post Link]
     , p.posttypeid
     , p.score
     , p.creationdate
     , p.tags
from tagposts tp
inner join posts p on tp.id = p.id
inner join posthistorytext pht on pht.postid = p.id
where pht.text like concat('%', @symbolsearch, '%')
order by score desc
```

Here is an example of the output:

[image: example output showing 16 post titles with score, creationdate and tags in the r tag with [<- as symbol]

Comment: Looks hike that this only search for a single string instead of e.g. posts that contain both string A and string B? (by the way, for the purpose of this question, top 50 ordered by score is probably what the user want)

Comment: @user202729 yes, it is only one search term. I'll add the order by in the query

Comment: Remark: It might be faster to query on `p.body` directly since it doesn't need the posthistory table, however if you do that you need to escape &lt; &gt; &amp; as well (not sure if there's anything else)

Comment: @user202729 it will be faster but also useless. p.body contains the rendered html of the post so it has way more fluff in it. By only taking the markdown into consideration its less prone to having false positives and if you go to a post and hit edit you see exactly the text that was considered in the search. Using post.body would make diagnosing false positives way harder. I didn't go through the trouble finding the last revision in the posthistory because it was quick or easy but because I wanted the query to be somewhat useful.

Comment: Remark2: use `concat(char(13), char(10))` to search for literal newline.

Answer (score -13):

I wouldn't bother about symbol search. Especially question mark (=wildcard in most places!)

Spell it out instead... And use Google, filtering with `site:stackoverflow.com`:

https://www.google.com/search?q=php+double+question+mark+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Or you can pick up a definition and try a new search. In this case, `""` helps,

```
php "null coalescing operator" site:stackoverflow.com
```

... read all about `??` in PHP, no problem.

Comment: This assumes there is a commonly accepted way to spell it out (be it akin to "double question mark" or more like "null coalescing operator"), and that the poster knows it or is otherwise able to guess it.

Comment: @duplode: Otherwise resulting in lots of "I didn't know what to search for", it's true. Although it would be nice if people dropped their lazy reliance on quick searching: it is still possible to simply _read the manual page on operators_ to find out what things do. Sadly the will to actually study has gone the way of the dinosaur; peeps ain't happy unless they can find their answer on Page 1 of Google, or get somebody here to spend their time creating a custom one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "peeps ain't happy unless they can find their answer on Page 1 of Google" actually, they ain't happy if the [breadcrums that google shows them is the actual answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233845/213575)

Comment: @Braiam: Gah! :( (lol)