# Are there ways to search on language operators; ex. R's "[<-" and "[[<-"

Tags: feature-request, search

One of the powerful features of [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) is the skilled use of assignment and extraction operators: `"[<-"`, `"[[<-"`, `"["`, `"[["`. The term I use for tagging questions is "indexing". There are also specialized operators built with non-alphabetic characters, for example: `"%in%"`. Searching for questions or answers might be improved by allowing the double quotes to be included in the searched-for string. But as far as I can determine, there's no capacity to search on questions that focus on the specific issues involving these operators because they are just "punctuation" in natural (English) language. The search for the operator "%in%" finds any instance of the two-letter string `in`. And the search for `[r] "[<-"` says it couldn't find anything.

I suspect this issue affects users of other languages, [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) being the most similar to R in this respect, but I know Python has operators for construction of lists and other data objects. I've tried searching for on this topic and found little, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong or pointed to documentation that I have not yet been able to find it.

Please do note that after Martijn Pieters' comments, I tried using `[r] code:"[<-"` (with exactly 0 results and `[r] code:[<-` (with over 1M results and equally useless).

Comment: searching for symbols on SE has always been a nightmare or non-existing.

Comment: There is the `code:` prefix but it has limited utility. See [Why aren't we told we can use special characters in search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867)

Comment: Symbol search is also **hard**, there are more edge cases than a rotorblade. Dedicated search engines like `symbolhound.com` have come and died, and even GitHub doesn't have symbol-based search.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you. So now I agree with Lauren that this should be highlighted and not just on the "Advanced" search page but on the ordinary Search:help page

Comment: This is the best I can do with the help of SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1591052?symbol=%5B%5B%5D%3C- notice the tricky encoding for the `[` it needs to be enclosed in a `[` and a `]` to return results.

Comment: @rene: It's too bad this was closed. I would have accepted that as an answer.

Comment: @IRTFM I have posted an answer on the duplicate, as we are supposed to do. I also made some slight adjustments so it is easier to use.

Comment: @rene Very helpful.

Comment: Historical note (2012): *"[Code searches are better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange/160740#160740)"* and *"[Chars such as +, - and underscores are no longer ignored in search terms which makes searches such as "_meta", "c++ books" and "c--" possible.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange/161142#161142)"*

Comment: [An answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32181/how-can-i-search-for-a-string-containing-a-colon/114629#114629) to an MSE question mentions the external "[SymbolHound](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters)", but it appears to be broken (though apparently [only for the past few weeks](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690)).